# Add Days in Cognos

Tags: filter, report, calculation, cognos, adhoc

I built this report in Cognos where I am using the _add_days( current_date, -1) as a query calculation as opposed to a filter. (When I had it as a filter, the report output would bring in previous dates, that are not part of the specified date under analysis.

For example, if I needed to see transactions that processed on 7/25/23 I was doing _add_days(current_date, -1).

When conducting analysis, the records also included transactions that weren't processed on 7/25/23. Dates from previous months and years are being included.

Figured by doing a query calculation, it would provide results for the exact date, but instead is only showing "False" instead of 7/25/23. Did I miss something or is my setup incorrect for the query calculation setup?

[image: Query Calculation ex]

[image: Filter ex]

(Companies old data warehouse was Teradata and now we are on Oracle until we move to Azure)

Comment: What would you expect the result to be if the data item expression was `1 = 2`?

Comment: If you want to filter a report then filter it.  You do not want to use a calculation to do your filter. You do not include your filter expression so I can't determine what you have done wrong.

Comment: @dougp, i was expecting the result to show transactions that processed on 7/25/23 only, since the _add_days(current_date,-1) would look at transaction that processed on 7/26/23 and back it up a day by showing 7/25/23 transactions only. the filter expression is the second image.

Comment: That calculation will return a boolean, which you presumably have observed.  You want to use a filter.

Comment: @C'estMoi thanks for the advice. the Boolean expression is the result I've been getting which is not the result seeking.

Comment: I guess "You do not include your filter expression so I can't determine what you have done wrong." went over your head.   Tell us the filter expression which you said did not produce the results you wanted.  I think your filter expression did exactly what was asked of it.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and then changed my approach to filter my report with this expression instead:

```
_days_between(current_date,[DATE Data Item]) = # DAYS
```